# nth-child looping for each

Tags: javascript, jquery

have a problem with this script.

```
var current = 1;

var height = $('.title').height(); 

var numberDivs = $('.title').children().length; 

var first = $('.title div:nth-child(1)'); 

setInterval(function() {
    var number = current * -height;
    first.css('margin-top', number + 'px');
    if (current === numberDivs) {
        first.css('margin-top', '0px');
        current = 1;
    } else current++;
}, 3000);
```

Now it append css style on fist div. I want to get him to list all one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop might suit you better.

```
var height = $('.title').height(); 

var numberDivs = $('.title').children().length;

var first = $('.title div:nth-child(1)');

for( var i = 1; i <= numberDivs; i++ ) {

    var number = current * -height;

    if( i == 1 ) {
         first.css('margin-top', number + 'px');
    }

    if (i === numberDivs) {
        first.css('margin-top', '0px');
        current = 1;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is what you need. If not I will need a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I try this but nothing happens

Comment: how can I do the previous div 0px?

Comment: Can you let me know exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a script who makes first div margin-top 70px after 2 seconds makes second div 70px and in same time  makes first div margin-top 0px  till the edn

Comment: So every 2 seconds you want to go down the list of divs and add a 70px margin-top to each while setting the rest to 0px?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate your selector with the `.each` function from jQuery, then you get something like this:

```
first.each(function(){
    this.css('margin-top', number + 'px');
}
```